# What's the meaning of "upon doing something"

Tags: prepositions

I come across the following sentence.

> Upon compiling his results for many thousands of plants, Mendel
>   concluded that the characteristics could be divided into what he
>   called dominant and recessive traits.

And I was told: After the first part (compile his result) was done, then he made a conclusion. Since it is using compiling which looks like part 1 and part 2 happened that same time. How do you thing?

Answer (score 5):

Upon doing something, someone realizes something.

On doing something,someone realizes something.

Those both mean: When that someone **did that thing**.

Upon reading this question, I was surprised.
On reading this question, I was surprised.

When I read this question, I was surprised.

Upon verb+ing is formal.

Answer (score 0):

*Upon compiling* here is almost the same as *On compiling*, which basically means he came to the conclusion after the compilation was done.